# vscodeで{ expectedscss(css-lcurlyexpected)というエラー

Tags: vscode, sass

vscodeの拡張機能でlive-sass-compilerを使ってsassをコンパイルしています。
以下のソースで

```
{ expectedscss(css-lcurlyexpected)
```

というエラーが出ました。どうすれば解決出来るでしょうか？

書いたsassは以下の通りです。

```
main {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      width: 800px;
    }
  }
}
```

エラー箇所は`width:800px;`の`:`部分です。

調べたところは同じ質問があったのですが、根本的な解決には至っていないような感じでした。

[stylus style formatting in vue files with VSCode - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443256/stylus-style-formatting-in-vue-files-with-vscode/52443683)

Comment: 記法って書けばよかったですかね？タグの説明にも2種類の構文とあるので自明だと思ったのですが…。作成したファイルの拡張子はなんでしょうか？`*.scss`でしょうか？表示されているエラーは`SCSS記法`で記述されているものを`SASS記法`でコンパイルを行おうとして`{`が出現したために、`予測SCSS記法`と警告が出ております。

Comment: あと、コンパイルするのであれば問題はないかと思いますが（コンパイラにもよる？）、一部ブラウザで`@media`のネストは認識されなかったと思いますのでお気をつけください。(具体的にはIE11とか)

Comment: @Sieg さん＞記法はscssです。＠media のネストのアドバイスありがとうございます！今、sassの学習中でして、とても勉強になります。つまり、このエラーは別に気にしなくて良いエラーということで良いのでしょうか？

Comment: @Sieg さん＞説明が下手ですみません。。。拡張子は元からscssでして勉強はsassのscss記法を学んでいる最中です。コンパイル自体も行われています。エラーは無視して良いということで安心しました！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私の伝え方が悪かったのかもしれません。
私の方では`PROBLEMS`に何も表示されないため、拡張子が違うこと原因ではないかと思いました。
`expected scss`(予測SCSS記法)というエラーを見たときに
「SCSS記法で警告が出ているのは拡張子`*.sass`だからでは？」と感じたからです。

私の方で再現させてみました。
現時点でネストしててもコンパイルはされているようですが、
先のコメントにも記載したとおり下記のようにネストをやめると`PROBLEMS`に何も表示されなくなると思います。

```
main {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    width: 800px;
  }
}
```

左がネスト有り、右がネスト無しになります。

[image: 検証]